# The Downside to addEventListener Versus onClick Property

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, listener

I understand the difference between an `addEventListener` and the `onclick` property and know how to use both. I am wondering if there is a draw back to always using `EventListener`'s instead of using the `onclick` property. The `EventListener` appears to be much more powerful than just using the `onclick` atleast when dynamically generating the HTML from javascript.

Is there a memory/cpu drawback or am I safe to only use EventListeners?

Comment: That sounds like micro-micro-optimization, so I have to ask: Why? Do you have a quadrillion events going on?

Comment: Yes I would need a few hundred actionlisteners

Comment: Several hundred shouldn't be noticeable, unless there's a really big difference. When you get into the millions start worrying about optimizing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably isn't the direction you were going in, but there are a few instances where you would be unable to remove an event listener.

Event handlers are completely public, and can be modified (to a certain extent) by anyone:

```
// You do this
myLink.onclick = function () {
    alert('hello, world');
};

// Another developer who hates you because
// he thinks that you're hitting on his girlfriend
// but you're not, you're just friends, but
// he's jealous so he doesn't understand
// does this
myLink.onclick = function () {
    alert('muahahahaha');
};

// Someone else could even get rid of
// the handler entirely:
myLink.onclick = null;
```

But there is no publically accessible list of event listeners. The only way to remove an event listener is if you still have access to the original function:

```
myLink.addEventListener('click', function () {
    alert('hello, world');
}, false);
```

There is now no way to remove that event listener. You gave it an anonymous function, so even you wouldn't be able to remove it if you wanted to.

Comment: Sorry I am really new to web-programming in general. Could you explain what you mean when you say someone could take ownership of my action listener?

Comment: Sadly [`EventListenerList`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20010823/events.html#Events-EventListenerList) never made it into the final draft.

Comment: @macneil I'm not sure what you mean by "ownership of the action listener."

Comment: So you're saying someone can pirate my page by injecting javascript and take ownership of my action listener? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @macneil That's one possibility. A lot of time, websites cancel right click by assigning an event handler to `document.oncontextmenu`. So if you wanted to reallow right click, you could just add a user script that sets `document.oncontextmenu = null`. Practically speaking, it doesn't really happen that much. It's just the libertarian in me that hates that any other script that I include on the page (ads, analytics, etc.) can mess with my event handlers.

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem for my application, but definitely worthwhile to consider. Thanks

Comment: +1 for interesting perspective and a great backstory in the code comments.